# Matching pattern including newline with OS X (BSD) sed

Tags: regex, macos, bash, sed, bsd

I want to match the following patterns using sed on OSX:

```
test = {
```

and

```
test =
{
```

I tried a lot of different things, including the line below but I can't figure out why it doesn't work:

```
sed -n -E -e "s/(^[a-zA-Z_]*[ ]*=[ "'\'$'\n'"]*{.*)/var \1/p" $path
```

I used the extquote $'\n' to match newline and included a backslash in front of it as I read on many posts on the internet. If I don't use any ( or [ groups it does work but I want to use the groups. I keep getting the following error:

```
sed: 1: "s/(^[a-zA-Z_]*[ ]*=[ \
 ...": unbalanced brackets ([])
```

Can anyone help me? I'm getting quite desperate.

Comment: Sed reads line demilted by newlines, you have to explicitly get the next line to perform a replacement on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work depending on what your exact data can be

```
sed '/[[:alpha:]]* =/{/ *{/!N;//s/^/var /;}' file
```

Input

```
test = {
blah
test =
{
wut
```

Output

```
var test = {
blah
var test =
{
wut
```

Comment: Thanks. I get a lot of matches with this pattern (a lot more than I want but maybe I can tweak that) but the newline still isn't matched ... maybe its impossible with this version of sed

Comment: What do you mean the newline isn't matched ? What problem are you having, does it work on the example input i have provided, if it does can you give me some that it doesn't work on ?

Comment: @Pieter-Jan Try it now, it was because  i had left a space at the end of the regex.

Comment: ok! that is perfect! you just lost my ^ at the beginning but now I get most the matches I want (except it also matches things like test = function () { which I don't want). Thank you so much! I don't really understand the command yet but I'll try ...